# Type `String.index (aka`string.CharacterView.index`)does not conform to protocol`_Strideable`

Tags: swift

I get Type `String.index` (aka `string.CharacterView.index`) does not conform to protocol `_Strideable`

[image: problem code picture]

How to solve this?

Comment: Could you post your code as text, not as an image?

Comment: Update to Swift 4. There is an initializer of `NSRange` which takes a `Range<String.Index>` in your example `let range = NSRange(stringRange, in: self)` and always prefer `matches.isEmpty` over `matches.count == 0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `String.Index` isn't `_Strideable`, but this code doesn't really make sense.

- `stringRange` is a `Range<String.CharacterView.Index>?`, which will measure grapheme clusters.
- `NSRegularExpression` is expecting an `NSString`, which is composed of UTF-16 code units.

At best, you get lucky and they're the same, and it's simply a much slower way to compute the length.  At worst, it's applying a regular expression to a substring that ends in the middle of a codepoint.

You should do something like this:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count)
```